# Передача регулярного выражения в метод replaceAll

Tags: java, строки

Есть строка - 12\n11\n43(пример)

Задача - переопределить строку, сделав из 12\n11\n43\n - 12,11,43.

`str = str.replaceAll("[\\n]",",");`

Проблема в создании регулярного выражения - код был взят из интернета.

Comment: `str = str.replace("\n",",");` / `str = str.replace("\\n",",");` - тут и регекс не нужен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String str = "12\n11\n43";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\n", ","));
// 12,11,43
```

Если в строке экранированные символы перевода, то:

```
String str = "12\\n11\\n43";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\\\n", ","));
// 12,11,43
```